# How to maintain the format of text while sharing as email using power automate

Tags: power-automate

I have created a flow, which extracts a .txt file from SharePoint and sends them in body of email using power automate. The flow is successful but the format part like, bold, space, paragraph etc; is not present. It just looks like continuous chunk of words. How to convert them back to proper format.

Edited!!

**Sample Input Text format and Expected output*

```
Q: What is global warming?
A: Since the Industrial Revolution, the global annual temperature has increased in total by a little more than 1 degree Celsius, or about 2 degrees Fahrenheit. 

 - Between 1880—the year that accurate recordkeeping began—and 1980, it rose on average by 0.07 degrees Celsius (0.13 degrees Fahrenheit) every 10 years.
 
 - The result? A planet that has never been hotter. 

 - Nine of the 10 warmest years since 1880 have occurred since 2005—and the 5 warmest years on record have all occurred since 2015.
```

**Received Output **

Q: What is global warming? A: Since the Industrial Revolution, the global annual temperature has increased in total by a little more than 1 degree Celsius, or about 2 degrees Fahrenheit. Between 1880—the year that accurate recordkeeping began—and 1980, it rose on average by 0.07 degrees Celsius (0.13 degrees Fahrenheit) every 10 years. The result? A planet that has never been hotter. Nine of the 10 warmest years since 1880 have occurred since 2005—and the 5 warmest years on record have all occurred since 2015.

**FLOW**

[image: FLOW]

Comment: We need more info, can you show us the contents of the file and the flow itself?  I have questions which can be answered by providing that information.

Comment: Added more details.. Kindly help

Comment: Put simply, the content needs to be in HTML. That’s what your file content should look like.